# Select one parent and one child with out extra queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end
```

and

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belogs_to :parent
end
```

I want to select one child from every parent for with out any extra queries what I need to do
I can do this by these lines

```
Parent.all.collect{|p| p.children.first}
```

but this is very poor approach and will run multiple queries I need a best way Which will return list of active records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get active record objects then make your call from other side und use SQL GROUP_BY:

```
Child.joins(:parent).group(:parent_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Following is the best approach to do the same thing and it will run queries just two times :

```
Parent.includes(:children).collect { |p| p.children.first }
```

for more details refer `Eager Loading Associations`section from [Rails Guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: This returns me an array I want active records objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be solved with a simple [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

```
Parent.includes(:children).map{|parent| parent.children.first }
```

that way you will perform two queries for the whole loop.

Comment: hi xlembouras this will load all the children from all the parent i want only one every parent and only one children to load from database.

Comment: This returns me an array I want active records objects